# Regex - Why does this allow spaces?

Tags: java, regex

Just a quick question, I'm writing a regex to allow ONLY letters (so just a words) and the following regex allows spaces, though I have not included them so why are they included?

```
([a-zA-Z])+
```

I've had to change it to this (pasted from Java):

```
([a-zA-Z]&&[^\\s])+
```

To provide context - I've tried this and input words with spaces and it still prints true:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter: ");
        String s = in.next();

        if (s.matches("[a-zA-Z]+")) {
            System.out.println("TRUE");
        }

    }
```

Comment: that doesn't allow spaces.  maybe you should show your problem code.

Comment: Added. Please see above.

Comment: The issue isn't in your regex; it's in your code.  `Scanner#next()` splits around spaces, so if you enter something such as "jumping dog", only "jumping" is passed to the test.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will always print TRUE as

```
String s = in.next();
```

uses the first token input by the user (delimited by space by Scanner).

Better to use:

```
String s = in.nextLine();
```

Answer (score 1):

Scanner is most likely splitting your input on spaces, and therefore you are matching a partial string.  You can confirm this by printing out the value of `s`.  As mentioned by others, you most likely want the `Scanner.nextLine()` method.

Answer (score 1):

The `Scanner` `.next()` method will get the next token, which will split upon spaces by default. Use `.nextLine()` instead.